# jQuery to slide a div right to left slides the div out of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have created a slider that slides from right to left. I am changing `margin-right` to make the slide work.

As per the requirement, I have a treeview, when user clicks on any node, it opens a sliding dialog with some controls in it. When user clicks on any node, it should first close the previously open dialog and then open the dialog for currently selected node. I am able to make this work when user clicks on the node, the dialog opens, and when user click back again on the same node or the slider-button, the dialog hides. But somehow, the code to hide when user click on any other node doesn't work properly. It moves the slider-button and the dialog away and I don't see anything.

I used the following code:

```
if($('#slider-button').css("margin-right") == "400px") {
    $(sliderDialog).animate({"margin-right": '-=400'});
    $('#slider-button').animate({"margin-right": '-=400'});
} else{
    $(sliderDialog).animate({"margin-right": '+=400'});
    $('#slider-button').animate({"margin-right": '+=400'});
}
```

I thought, it as simple as finding if the previously selected dialog is different than current than just call the same code that hides the dialog when user clicks on the same node again. ie.

```
$(sliderDialog).animate({"margin-right": '-=400'});
$('#slider-button').animate({"margin-right": '-=400'});
```

But, it behaves weird. Anyone, what am I missing here?

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuul13/XNnHC/981/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the DOM and such that you had, I've updated the JS to switch between them after animating back (here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEVH8/2/) in action):

```
var sliderDialog = "#dvPriorityDialog"

function slideIt() {
    var sliderId = '#' + $('.pollSlider.open').attr('id');
    var slideWidth;
    if ($('.pollSlider').hasClass('open')) {
        slideWidth = $('.pollSlider.open').width();
        $('.pollSlider.open').animate({"margin-right": '-=' + slideWidth}, function() {
           if (sliderId != sliderDialog) {
                slideIt();
           }
        });
        $('#slider-button').animate({"margin-right": '-=' + slideWidth});
        $('.pollSlider.open').removeClass('open');
    }  else {
        slideWidth = $(sliderDialog).width();
        $(sliderDialog).addClass('open');
        $('#slider-button').animate({"margin-right": '+=' + slideWidth});
        $(sliderDialog).animate({"margin-right": '+=' + slideWidth});
    }
}

function bindControls() {
    $('#slider-button').click(function() {
       slideIt(); 
    });
    $("#liPriority").click(function() {
        sliderDialog = "#dvPriorityDialog";
        slideIt();

    });
    $("#liFasting").click(function() {
        sliderDialog = "#dvFastingDialog";
        slideIt();
    });
}

// init;
$(document).ready(function() {
    bindControls();
 });
```

Comment: Although this is a perfect solution to what I ask. I somehow struggled to make this work for one of the scenarios that I encountered today. I realized couple of nodes will open a dialog with different size (width). Do I need to store different width in array/variables and then use in the SlideIt() function or there is simplified way to do so? Please suggest. Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kuul13/wEVH8/1/

Comment: The simplest method would be to get the width of the element you're going to animate, and use that for the margin rather than set a hard value.

Comment: So you mean to get the width of the current animation dialog's width instead of the hardcoded values that are there right now in slideit method?

Comment: Updated the answer (and fiddle) above to include your request.

Answer (score 0):

Try

$(sliderDialog).stop().animate({"margin-right": '-=400'});

$('#slider-button').stop().animate({"margin-right": '-=400'});

Comment: I tried it but still not getting what is required. Here is my updated  http://jsfiddle.net/kuul13/XNnHC/987/

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems :

1. You try to move a same element (#slider-button) in function of two different animations (a panel go left and an other go right). To resolve that, the best option is to add a button to each panel. It will be a lot easier to manage global behavior because you have only one animation by panel.
2. You don't stop animation when you want to change them. Store your animation in vars and use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function with the first param to true in you case (`.stop(true)` to stop animation and remove it from queue without finish it).
3. Your state test is based on your animated css attribute (margin-right). So you alltime have to wait the end of animation to start the new one. To fix that use vars to store your animations state : (`var firstPanelLastMove = 'left' // or right` ... etc).

Comment: I can have different #slider-button but it is just nice to have button. I didn't get how to store the animation in the variables? and use them to stop and animate?

Comment: When a dialog will go to left and the other go back to right what will be the button behavior ? Go back to right then go to left to follow the other dialog ? Two button is a lot easier. For variables, if you don't want to store animation in your var just stop animation on the element : `$(element).stop(true)`

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I need to get my head around it though.